# Filter and iterate over pandas dataframe based on dictionary values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am trying to iterate through a pandas dataframe to create filter conditions and below is my code which works fine:-

```
categories_lst = [
        ["BEER/ALE/ALCOHOLIC CIDER"],
        ["CIGARETTES", "CIGARS", "ELECTRONIC SMOKING DEVICES"],
        ["COLD CEREAL"],
        ["YOGURT"],
    ]
    threshold_lst = [1, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]
    i = 0
    for lst in categories_lst:
        # filtering category
        df_report = df_us_brand_report[df_us_brand_report["category"].isin(lst)]
        df_report = df_report[abs(df_report["change"]) >= threshold_lst[i]]
        print(lst)
        print(threshold_lst[i])
        i += 1
       # some other operations
```

However, I want to optimize it, I tried using the below code and it fails because list is not hashable.

```
category_dict = {
        ["BEER/ALE/ALCOHOLIC CIDER"]: 1,
        ["CIGARETTES", "CIGARS", "ELECTRONIC SMOKING DEVICES"]: 0.25,
        ["COLD CEREAL"]: 0.25,
        ["YOGURT"]: 0.25,
    }
    for condition, value in category_dict:
        filter_condition = (df_us_brand_report["category"].isin(condition)) & (
            abs(df_us_brand_report["change"]) >= value
        )

        # some other operations
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Data Sample:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tuples:

```
category_dict = {
        ("BEER/ALE/ALCOHOLIC CIDER", ): 1,
        ("CIGARETTES", "CIGARS", "ELECTRONIC SMOKING DEVICES"): 0.25,
        ("COLD CEREAL", ): 0.25,
        ("YOGURT", ): 0.25,
    }

for condition, value in category_dict.items():
    filter_condition = (df_us_brand_report["category"].isin(list(condition))) & (
            abs(df_us_brand_report["change"]) >= value)
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael,
Could you tell me the reason why this evaluates to empty?

df_us_brand_report[df_us_brand_report["category"].isin(list(condition))]
I am trying -
filter_condition = (df_us_brand_report["category"].isin(list(condition))) & (
            abs(df_us_brand_report["change"]) >= value)
df_us_brand_report = df_us_brand_report[filter_condition] which returns empty

Comment: @PrakharJhudele - Is possible ad some sample data of `DataFrame` for verify problem?

Comment: added in the original q

Comment: @PrakharJhudele - Tested sampel data and riase error? If yes, is possible share like text?

Comment: if I print it by giving value as print((df_us_brand_report[df_us_brand_report["category"].isin(["BEER/ALE/ALCOHOLIC CIDER"])]) it works fine

Comment: @PrakharJhudele - So data in question working well? Is possible find data which failed with solution above?

Comment: yes sample data is working fine. I will try and find failing cases.

Comment: possibly this might be the reason
list(condition) gives me

['B', 'E', 'E', 'R', '/', 'A', 'L', 'E', '/', 'A', 'L', 'C', 'O', 'H', ...]

Comment: @PrakharJhudele - Sorry, Maybe problem in my first code was error - `("BEER/ALE/ALCOHOLIC CIDER")` instead `("BEER/ALE/ALCOHOLIC CIDER", )` - missing last `,`, sorry.

Comment: @PrakharJhudele - I think for one element tuple need `,`

Comment: Yup you right !!Got the reason "Tuple with one element. If the tuple contains only one element, then it's not considered as a tuple. It should have a trailing comma to specify the interpreter that it's a tuple."

Answer (score 0):

For dictionary keys you have to use immutable objects like tuples, strings or int etc.